# Scala pattern matching over Object

Tags: scala

Can anybody explain pattern matching over Object behavior. 
Are two objects of same class are same?

```
object Solution extends App {
  case class EE() { }
  object EE1 extends EE
  object EE2 extends EE
  val k: EE = EE1
  println(k.getClass) // class Solution$EE1$
  println(k.isInstanceOf[EE2.type]) // returns FALSE
  println(k.getClass.isInstanceOf[EE2.type.getClass]) // returns FALSE
  k match {
    case EE2 => println("EE1 match EE2!!!") // MATCH THIS LINE/// WHY???
    case EE1 => println("EE1 match EE1. OK!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `case EE2` in a match, it checks matched object for equality with `EE2` (note that if the identifier started with a lower-case letter, Lee's answer would be correct; this rule exists specifically to make matching `object`s and constants, whose names normally start with upper-case letters, make sense). But because `EE1` and `EE2` both extend `case class EE()`, they are equal (you can check directly with `EE1 == EE2` or `k == EE2`). It works as expected if you make them unequal [by removing `case`](http://scastie.org/11845):

```
object Solution extends App {
  class EE() { }
  object EE1 extends EE
  object EE2 extends EE
  val k: EE = EE1
  println(k.getClass) // class Solution$EE1$
  println(k.isInstanceOf[EE2.type]) // returns FALSE
  k match {
    case EE2 => println("EE1 match EE2!!!") // MATCH THIS LINE/// WHY???
    case EE1 => println("EE1 match EE1. OK!")
  }
}


Processing...
Reused last reload result
[info] Loading project definition from /tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/project
[info] Set current project to rendererWorker (in build file:/tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/)
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to rendererWorker (in build file:/tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/)

[info] Formatting 1 Scala source {file:/tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/}rendererWorker(compile) ...
[info] Reformatted 1 Scala source {file:/tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/}rendererWorker(compile).
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/renderer9oHZD8Bvx9/target/classes...
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 19, 2015 1:13:04 PM
Now running...
[info] Running Solution 
class Solution$EE1$
false
EE1 match EE1. OK!
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 19, 2015 1:13:04 PM
```